# using !Ref in second argument in SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, intrinsics, sam

The below code is giving me error:

```
NOTIFICATION_ARN: !Sub
    -  'arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${stage}-${ServiceName}'
    -  ServiceName: !Ref ServiceName
    -  stage: !Ref Stage
```

error:Template error: `One or more Fn::Sub intrinsic functions don't specify expected arguments. Specify a string as first argument, and an optional second argument to specify a mapping of values to replace in the string`

How can I resolve this error? Stage is defined inside parameter section in sam template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one too many `-`. It should be:

```
NOTIFICATION_ARN: !Sub
    -  'arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${stage}-${ServiceName}'
    -  ServiceName: !Ref ServiceName
       stage: !Ref Stage
```